# Pass multidimensional array from ajax to action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble getting data from an AJAX call to my action.  Here is how I build my array on the javascript side of things:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function (index){
    if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf("UniqueID_") > -1) {
        savedParams.uniqueIds.push([$(this).attr('id'), $(this).is(":checked")]);
    }
});
```

I then make my ajax call:

```
return $.get('<%= Url.Action("GridData") %>', savedParams).done(
    function(rows, status, xhr) {
        doSomething();
    });
```

When I hit the endpoint, the dictionary populates with the right amount of entries, but the values are all wrong.  Here is my endpoint:

```
public ActionResult GridData(Dictionary<string,bool> uniqueIds = null)
```

Capturing the request in Fiddler shows that the format seems to be correct:

```
GET /Transactions/GridData?2%5B0%5D%5B%5D=UniqueID_1&uniqueIds%5B0%5D%5B%5D=true&uniqueIds%5B1%5D%5B%5D=UniqueID_2&uniqueIds%5B1%5D%5B%5D=true&uniqueIds%5B2%5D%5B%5D=UniqueID_3&uniqueIds%5B2%5D%5B%5D=true HTTP/1.1
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by the values are all wrong? how are they wrong?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that.  So I'll get three entries in my dictionary:

{0, null}
{1, null}
{2, null}

Comment: 1) a multi-dimensional array is *not* the same thing as a dictionary 2) Your JS is pushing a list composed of the id as one item and the checked status as another item, not a key-value pair, as you most likely think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass back a dictionary to the method, your javascript object needs to be in the following format

```
var savedParams = { 'uniqueIds[0].key': 'ABC', 'uniqueIds[0].value': 'True', 'uniqueIds[1].key': 'DEF', 'uniqueIds[1].value': 'True', .... };
```

However you should not be passing a dictionary to a GET method. Apart from the ugly query string your creating, you could easily exceed the query string character limit and throw an exception. Instead post the data.

In any case, you avoid all this by using a view model (say with properties `string ID` and `bool IsSelected` and properly constructing your html using HtmlHelpers in a `for` loop so you can post back to `public ActionResult GridData(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model)`. Then its simply `savedParams = $('form').serialize();`

Comment: After some consideration, I realized I was really trying to force something that I probably didn't need to be forcing.  I was able to rewrite some of my code so I didn't need to pass a multidimensional array and instead just passed a comma separated string.  As you stated, the query string was ugly.

If I had the time to go back and do it differently, a view model would have been a much cleaner way to go about it.  Thank you for the extra information!